# Complex integral when there are singularities on the path

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I try to integrate $I=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1+acos\theta}d\theta$. A possible solution is let $z=e^{i\theta}$ and so $I=\oint_c \frac{1}{1+a \frac{z+z^{-1}}{2}}\frac{dz}{iz}=\frac{1}{i}\oint_c \frac{dz}{az^2+2z+a} $(where counter c is unit circle), then i can caculate residue to find this integral. I let $az^2+2z+a=0$ so $z_1=\frac{1}{a}(-1+\sqrt{1-a^2})\ and\ z_2=\frac{1}{a}(-1-\sqrt{1-a^2})$, if |a|<1, is easy to caculate the residue because there are no poles on the unit circle. However, when |a| is lager than 1, $|z_1|=|\frac{1}{a}(-1+i\sqrt{a^2-1})|=1\ and\ |z_2|=|\frac{1}{a}(-1-i\sqrt{a^2-1})|=1$ so there are two poles on this path, how can i handle it?

Comment: The integral does not exist in that case.

Comment: Really? How can i prove it?

Comment: For principal value, make a small detour to avoid them and you will see it picks up half the residue at those simple poles.

Comment: Look at the behviour of $1+ a\cos \theta $ around a point where $\cos \theta=-\frac 1 a$. BTW, I am talking about Lebesgue integral. You may have a Cauchy's principal value for $I$.

Comment: How to find the principal value? I don't know how to choose the path to avoid the poles.

Comment: One scheme is like this, when (as here) the singularity is a pole.  Integrate along a small semicircle around the singularity.  Do it twice, once on each side.  Then average the values.  Call it the "principal value".